# Set / Copy javascript computed style from one element to another

Tags: javascript, copy, set, clone, computed-style

So I am trieing to copy all the style that apply on one element ( class / id / tagName / attribute etc. ).
So far I found out that I can copy the computed style of an element,
Just one problem ... couldend apply it on outher element ;/

or diffrend way to copy all the style.

(this is as far as i got :/ )
http://jsfiddle.net/8KdJd/2/

```
   //queriks mode + minor changes to retrive the computed style
function getCS(el)
{
    if (el.currentStyle)
        var y = el.currentStyle;
    else if (window.getComputedStyle)
        var y = document.defaultView.getComputedStyle(el,null);
    return y;
}
function setCS(el,cs)
{
    if (el.currentStyle)
    {

        el.currentStyle = cs;
        el.style = cs;
    }
    else if (window.getComputedStyle)
    {el.style = cs 
    }

}


var myLink = document.getElementById('myLink');
var anotherLink = document.getElementById('anotherLink');

var CS_myLink = getCS(myLink);
setCS(anotherLink,CS_myLink);
```

Comment: Is there a specific reason why you need to copy the style like this? According to this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/344162/set-html-elements-style-property-in-javascript you cannot just assign a "style object" to an element's `style` attribute like what you've done in your `setCS` function. A much easier way of doing this would be change the CSS definition of `#myLink` to a class like `.myLink`, then use Javascript to add the class `myLink` to the second link element.

Comment: Hi thx for the response,
Yes there is a reason that im doing it that way,
My code will apply on already built websites which not in my control.

Comment: so I got it work on webkit ( chrome so far) with the following code,
Problem is that IE return empty string for .cssText property

http://jsfiddle.net/8KdJd/4/

function setCS(el,cs)
{
 if (el.currentStyle)
    {
        **el.style.cssText = cs.cssText;**
    }
 else if (window.getComputedStyle)
    {
        el.style.cssText = cs.cssText;
    }

Comment: if you are able to add Javascript, can you add CSS as well to that website?

Comment: Hi jingtao, i guess i can.
but i will need to check all the following:
Attributes,css,id,inheritness 
and its much more complicated to accomplish

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Update: 
As @icl7126 suggested, here is a shorter version for practically the same usage.
good thing to remember that this code would not run on most/older browser if not pre-compiled.

Original (ES 2017):

```
function copyNodeStyle(sourceNode, targetNode) {
  const computedStyle = window.getComputedStyle(sourceNode);
  Array.from(computedStyle).forEach(key => targetNode.style.setProperty(key, computedStyle.getPropertyValue(key), computedStyle.getPropertyPriority(key)))
}
```

Precompiled (ES 5):

```
function copyNodeStyle(sourceNode, targetNode) {
  var computedStyle = window.getComputedStyle(sourceNode);
  Array.from(computedStyle).forEach(function (key) {
    return targetNode.style.setProperty(key, computedStyle.getPropertyValue(key), computedStyle.getPropertyPriority(key));
  });
}
```

#

**original answer posted on Nov '13. CSS variables were not supported back then. (first introduces on firefox on Jul 2014)**

#

Thats it! I got it :)

Iv'e seen that lots of people view this question,
So below is more detailed and clean code.

```
var copyComputedStyle = function(from,to){
    var computed_style_object = false;
    //trying to figure out which style object we need to use depense on the browser support
    //so we try until we have one
    computed_style_object = from.currentStyle || document.defaultView.getComputedStyle(from,null);

    //if the browser dose not support both methods we will return null
    if(!computed_style_object) return null;

        var stylePropertyValid = function(name,value){
                    //checking that the value is not a undefined
            return typeof value !== 'undefined' &&
                    //checking that the value is not a object
                    typeof value !== 'object' &&
                    //checking that the value is not a function
                    typeof value !== 'function' &&
                    //checking that we dosent have empty string
                    value.length > 0 &&
                    //checking that the property is not int index ( happens on some browser
                    value != parseInt(value)

        };

    //we iterating the computed style object and compy the style props and the values 
    for(property in computed_style_object)
    {
        //checking if the property and value we get are valid sinse browser have different implementations
            if(stylePropertyValid(property,computed_style_object[property]))
            {
                //applying the style property to the target element
                    to.style[property] = computed_style_object[property];

            }   
    }   

};
```

Comment: Not sure if it is rubbish code or you are just a damn genius, but this does so incredibly well what I was looking for! You should accept your own answer.

Comment: It might be simpler to use getComputedStyle(element).cssText to get all styles

Comment: Read the third comment for the question. QOUTE "Problem is that IE return empty string for .cssText property"

Comment: setPropety and getPropertyValue will work with css variables but last code will not work with them.

Comment: The last code is the original answer posted on Nov '13. CSS variables were not supported back then. (first introduces on firefox on Jul 2014)

Comment: This solution no longer works, recently an update to Chrome and Firefox no longer allows indexable setter access to style declarations (e.g. to.style[property]). You can use most of the solution, you just have to manually allocate each to.style.{prop} = computed_style_object.{prop}. You can see a similar conversation on this issue for react at  https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/15375

Answer (score 7):

A bit shorter solution using `setProperty`, `getPropertyValue` and `getPropertyPriority`.

```
function copyNodeStyle(sourceNode, targetNode) {
  const computedStyle = window.getComputedStyle(sourceNode);
  Array.from(computedStyle).forEach(key => targetNode.style.setProperty(key, computedStyle.getPropertyValue(key), computedStyle.getPropertyPriority(key)))
}
```

**Useful MDN docs: [getComputedStyle](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle) and [CSSStyleDeclaration](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSStyleDeclaration)**

Answer (score 1):

Computed styles do not retain priority information (`... !important`) so `getComputedStyle()` will not return style priorities and therefore `computedStyle.getPropertyPriority(key)` above (in the accepted answer) will not work - it will always return `''`.

If you want to ensure the computed styles always take priority then explicitly set the priority:

```
function copyNodeStyle(sourceNode, targetNode) {
  const computedStyle = window.getComputedStyle(sourceNode);
  Array.from(computedStyle).forEach(
    key => targetNode.style.setProperty(key, computedStyle.getPropertyValue(key), 'important')
  )
}
```