# Javascript: How to set css style generated from getComputedStyles() into a button

Tags: javascript, css

I want to add all the computed style that will be generated using `getComputedStyle()` into another button.
I have tried with `.cssText` but it seems something else needs to be done here.
any suggestion what can be required to make this happen.

//get styles and storing into sessionstorage

```
const getStyle = getComputedStyle(document.getElementById("testButton"));
sessionStorage.setItem("getStylesItem", JSON.stringify(getStyle));
```

//set styles from session object into a button

```
const jsonValue = JSON.parse(sessionStorage["getStylesItem"]);
const elem = document.getElementById('TestButton1');
elem.style.cssText = jsonValue.cssText;
```

//dummy json value

```
{
alignContent: "normal",
alignItems: "center",
alignSelf: "auto",
alignmentBaseline: "auto",
all: "",
animation: "none 0s ease 0s 1 normal none running",
animationDelay: "0s",
animationDirection: "normal",
animationDuration: "0s",
animationFillMode: "none"
}
```

[image]

Comment: `jsonValue.cssText` – does your JSON value actually have such a property? (Can’t tell from the shortented example you have shown.)

Comment: @04FS thanks for your time. So I want to apply all the styles into another button. Any tricks to do so?

Comment: create a css class and store all style in it. Store css class name in sessionStorage and apply css class when you want to reuse on another button.

Comment: You will have to loop over the object you got there. You could either try and assemble a string that can be assigned to `cssText` from that - but then you will probably have to undo the camelCasing (I don’t think assigning to cssText will work with that.) Assigning each of them directly might make more sense, that works with the camelCase property names as they are.

Comment: If i apply each with property from my json then it will be hardcoded. So want to apply as it is so it will be more robust or future.

Comment: @Tammy check my answer. i edited some typos.

Comment: Duplicate of [Set / Copy javascript computed style from one element to another](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19784064/215552)

Comment: I think that the answer here proves that this question is not overly broad, and should be reopened.

Comment: @AndyMercer I would think we'd just close it as a duplicate of the link I posted though...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Loop the CSS object and then form a string. You should use the inline styles for cssText.

```
const jsonValue = JSON.parse(sessionStorage["getStylesItem"]);
const elem = document.getElementById('TestButton1');

let cssText = '';
for (const property in jsonValue) {
  if (!Number.isNaN(parseInt(property))) continue;
  cssText += `${property}:${jsonValue[property]}`;
}

elem.style.cssText = cssText;
```

`CSSStyleDeclaration` object has numeric properties like `0: "align-content", 1: "align-items"` so you need to filter non-numeric properties only.

Comment: Hi Thank you for your time. Getting an error of 
Uncaught ReferenceError: styles is not defined

Comment: is it styles[property] ? or style[property]

Comment: ah my bad. it should be `jsonValue[property]`

Comment: thats perfect. Some adjustments is there which I will do. thank you for your time.

Comment: you are welcome. you can filter the existing properties so make it simple.

Comment: One small thing i noticed that it is currently not picking the value from ex: borderRadius . It is taking border not not borderRadius .

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/222077/discussion-between-tammy-and-polyglot).

Answer (score 1):

This can achieved by using `for loop` as well.

//For setting seesion storage

```
const button = document.getElementById("test");
if (button) {
  const getStyle = getComputedStyle(button);
  let testStyle = {};
  for (const key in getStyle) {
    testStyle[key] = getStyle[key];
  }
  sessionStorage.setItem("testStyles", JSON.stringify(testStyle));
}
```

//For getting the value and apply in your button

```
  const elem = document.getElementById('button1');
  const getParam = sessionStorage(JSON.parse["testStyles"]);
  if (elem && getParam) {
    const elemStyle = elem.style;
    if (elemStyle) {
      for (const key in getParam) {
        elemStyle[key] = getParam[key];
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: Nice solution though.